# Is it good for me to switch to Moralis from web3js?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, moralis

I've used web3.js for a long time now for connecting my front-end ( ReactJs ) with blockchain.
I wanted to switch to ethers but heard about Moralis . Now I am really confused about what to choose ? ( weekly downloads of ethers is way more than that of web3 , this was the main reason I wanted to switch , I watched some youtube videos claiming ethers to be better ) . Can anyone help me pick the right one among Web3.js , Ethers.js and Moralis ?

Answer (score 3):

Ether js and web3 js are the de facto to be used in web3 to interact with the blockchain. Moralis is a third party service which is, obviously, a paid service.

In the world of blockchain and decentralization, ether js and web3 js keep the sprit of anonymity while moralis, under the hood, though is using web3 or ether js will keep track of the activities of the users like transaction data, ip address, devices info etc.

Though using moralis, you will find a fun way to work in web3 because it is very easy to use moralis libraries than making own functions in etherjs and web3 js.

But at the end it is up to you what track you want to choose. I support moralis and its work because it has made the etherjs and web3 js easy to use in our dAaps.

Comment: Noted @Safi . Thank you for this satisfactory answer . Which one among ethers and web3js do you use more for building DApps ? since I got to know from @ PSS that Moralis is paid .

Answer (score 3):

Moralis is not equal to Ethers or Web3.js. It is not apples to apple comparison. Moralis is a commercial Web3 Data, Streams, and Authentication API. It has recently transitioned to be utilized as a backend SDK only. Moralis is becoming more like a backend blockchain data provider (paid, by the way). The front end moved to a package called [moralis-v1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moralis-v1). I am curious to know how well it will get supported in the future.

[Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/), on the other hand, is, and I quote:

> The ethers.js library aims to be a complete and compact library for interacting with the Ethereum Blockchain and its ecosystem originally designed for use with ethers.io and has since expanded into a more general-purpose library.

In my opinion, if your goal is to develop complete Web3 projects, you must know Ethers.js and combine that with other libraries and SDKs, such as [Wagmi](https://wagmi.sh/), [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/), [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) to mention a few.

At this point, Ethers.js is a dependency for many libraries and SDKs. Learning it will be very beneficial, if not a must.

Just my $0.02. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks @PSS . I think I should start learning ethersjs for good . Do you use ethers from the beginning or have switched from web3js ?

Comment: I've never used web3js, only Ethers.js

Comment: Hey @PSS thanks for answering, I'm from Moralis and I can clarify that the moralis-v1 is mostly deprecated, we are no longer maintaining it. However, people can use it with mostly limited functionality and a lot of maintenance on their own now.

We focus mostly on providing the API which could be useful to efficiently index various data from the blockchain, but true it is definitely a different use case compare to the likes of web3js or ethers