# Can't load data from smartcontract using react-moralis useWeb3Contract() hook and useEffect() hook

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, moralis, nextjs

I have a contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./Voting.sol";

contract VotingEngine is Ownable {
    Voting[] public votings;
    mapping(address => Voting[]) public ownerToVotings;

    //constructor() {}

    function createVoting(
        string memory _question,
        string[] memory _candidates,
        uint256 _duration,
        uint256 _quorum
    ) public {
        votings.push(new Voting(_question, _candidates, _duration, _quorum));
        ownerToVotings[msg.sender].push(votings[votings.length - 1]);
    }

    function getVoting(uint256 index) public view returns (Voting) {
        return votings[index];
    }

    function getVotingsCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return votings.length;
    }

    function getVotingQuestion(uint256 index) public view returns (string memory) {
        return votings[index].getQuestion();
    }
}
```

I have an index.js page made with nextjs, i try to load data from this smartcontract and it's not working.
index.js:

```js
import Head from "next/head"
import Image from "next/image"
import { Inter } from "next/font/google"
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css"
import Header from "@/components/Header"
import { useMoralis, useWeb3Contract } from "react-moralis"
import Card from "@/components/Card"
import Footer from "@/components/Footer"
import { contractAddresses, votingEngAbi, votingAbi } from "@/constants"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useNotification } from "web3uikit"
import { ethers } from "ethers"
import Web3 from "web3"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] })
const supportedChains = ["31337", "5", "80001", "11155111"]

export default function Home() {
    const { chainId: chainIdHex, isWeb3Enabled } = useMoralis()
    const chainId = parseInt(chainIdHex)
    const votingEngAddress = chainId in contractAddresses ? contractAddresses[chainId][0] : null

    let [votingsCount, setVotingsCount] = useState(0)
    let [votingAddress, setvotingAddress] = useState("0x")
    let [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
    let [id, setId] = useState(0)

    const { runContractFunction: getVotingsCount } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingEngAbi,
        contractAddress: votingEngAddress,
        functionName: "getVotingsCount",
        params: {},
        //msgValue: [],
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getVoting } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingEngAbi,
        contractAddress: votingEngAddress,
        functionName: "getVoting",
        params: { index: id },
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getQuestion } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingAbi,
        contractAddress: votingAddress,
        functionName: "getQuestion",
        params: {},
    })

    const {
        runContractFunction: getVotingQuestion,
        isFetching,
        isLoading,
    } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingEngAbi,
        contractAddress: votingEngAddress,
        functionName: "getVotingQuestion",
        params: { index: id },
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        async function updateUIValues() {
            const votingsCountFromCall = (await getVotingsCount()).toNumber()
            setVotingsCount(votingsCountFromCall)
            console.log("Count: " + votingsCount)

            //if (votingsCount > 0) {
            for (; id < votingsCount; ) {
                console.log(id)
                //const addressVotingFromCall = await getVoting()
                //setvotingAddress(addressVotingFromCall)

                const questionFromCall = await getVotingQuestion()
                console.log("Question: " + questionFromCall)
                setQuestions([...questions, questionFromCall])

                console.log(questions)
                console.log(isLoading)
                console.log(isFetching)
                //setId(id + 1)
                id++
            }
        }

        if (isWeb3Enabled) {
            updateUIValues()
        } else {
            //setVotingsCount(0)
            setQuestions([])
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Smart Contract Voting System</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Smart Contract Voting System" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Header />

            <div
                onClick={() => {
                    console.log(votingsCount)
                }}
            >
                Votings count: {votingsCount}
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4 grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4 justify-items-center">
                {votingsCount > 0 ? (
                    questions.map((q, index) => <Card key={index} question={q} id={index} />)
                ) : (
                    <Card question={"Nothing there"} />
                )}
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

When i load a page i see this [image]

I have 2 votings created, but i can't see it on my frontend, i can't understand why, help me, please

Smartcontract voting system repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/ThatsTheSpirit/smartcontract-voting-system)

Nextjs voting system repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/ThatsTheSpirit/nextjs-smartcontract-voting-system)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would add **[isWeb3Enabled]** dependency to your **useEffect()** dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ...
        }
    }, [isWeb3Enabled])
```

When you include variables or state values in the dependencies array, the effect will only run when those values change. If the dependencies array is empty (such as in your case), the effect will only run once when the component mounts and not again unless the component is unmounted and mounted again. Most likely, when your component is mounted **isWeb3Enabled** is still **false**; thus, your code never runs.

**UPDATE**

I looked at your code in your repo, and it seems that your contract VotingEngine.sol is not loaded with any data after deployment, which is why your front end is not getting anything. In your deployment script for the contract `02-deploy-votingEngine.js` you just deploy the contract. You never call createVoting() function of the contract to add `votings` to your contract. The `votings` array is empty. Thus it returns 0 when you call getVotingsCount(). To fix the issue, update your `02-deploy-votingEngine.js` to this:

```js
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    const question = networkConfig[chainId]["question"]
    const candidates = networkConfig[chainId]["candidates"]
    const duration = networkConfig[chainId]["duration"]
    const quorum = networkConfig[chainId]["quorum"]

    const args = []

    await deploy("VotingEngine", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    log("Checking votings...")
    const votingEngine = await ethers.getContract("VotingEngine", deployer)
    const votingsCounts = await votingEngine.getVotingsCount()
    log(`Found ${votingsCounts} votings`)
    if (votingsCounts == 0) {
        log("Creating voting...")
        await votingEngine.createVoting(question, candidates, duration, quorum)
    }

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(votingEngine.address, args)
    }
    log("---------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "votingEngine"]
```

Then you need to update your front end like so:

```js
import Head from "next/head"
import Image from "next/image"
import { Inter } from "next/font/google"
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css"
import Header from "@/components/Header"
import { useMoralis, useWeb3Contract } from "react-moralis"
import Card from "@/components/Card"
import Footer from "@/components/Footer"
import { contractAddresses, votingEngAbi, votingAbi } from "@/constants"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useNotification } from "web3uikit"
import { ethers } from "ethers"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] })
const supportedChains = ["31337", "5", "80001", "11155111"]

export default function Home() {
    const { chainId: chainIdHex, isWeb3Enabled } = useMoralis()
    const chainId = parseInt(chainIdHex)
    const votingEngAddress = chainId in contractAddresses ? contractAddresses[chainId][0] : null

    let [votingsCount, setVotingsCount] = useState(0)
    let [votingAddress, setvotingAddress] = useState("0x")
    let [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
    let [id, setId] = useState(0)

    const { runContractFunction: getVotingsCount } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingEngAbi,
        contractAddress: votingEngAddress,
        functionName: "getVotingsCount",
        params: {}, //add question, candidates, duration, quorum through props
        //msgValue: [],
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getVoting } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingEngAbi,
        contractAddress: votingEngAddress,
        functionName: "getVoting",
        params: { index: id },
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getQuestion } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingAbi,
        contractAddress: votingAddress,
        functionName: "getQuestion",
        params: {},
    })

    const {
        runContractFunction: getVotingQuestion,
        isFetching,
        isLoading,
    } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: votingEngAbi,
        contractAddress: votingEngAddress,
        functionName: "getVotingQuestion",
        params: { index: id },
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        async function updateUIValues() {
            const votingsCountFromCall = await getVotingsCount()
            console.log(votingsCountFromCall)
            console.log(votingEngAddress)

            setVotingsCount(Number(votingsCountFromCall))

            //if (votingsCount > 0) {
            for (let counter = 0; counter < votingsCount; counter++) {
                console.log(id)
                //const addressVotingFromCall = await getVoting()
                //setvotingAddress(addressVotingFromCall)

                const questionFromCall = await getVotingQuestion()
                console.log("Question: " + questionFromCall)
                setQuestions([...questions, questionFromCall])
            }
        }

        if (isWeb3Enabled) {
            updateUIValues()
        } else {
            //setVotingsCount(0)
            //setQuestions([])
        }
    }, [isWeb3Enabled])

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Smart Contract Voting System</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Smart Contract Voting System" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Header />

            <div>Votings count: {votingsCount}</div>
            <div className="mt-4 grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4 justify-items-center">
                {votingsCount > 0 ? (
                    questions.map((q, index) => <Card key={index} question={q} id={index} />)
                ) : (
                    <Card question={"Nothing there"} />
                )}
                {/* <Card />
                <Card />
                <Card />
                <Card /> */}
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

You get your front end responding as it should:
[image: Front Page][image: Console.log()][image: Click Event]

FYI, I created pull requests on both of your GitHub repositories with this fixed.

Comment: i tried it, if i add it ```const votingsCountFromCall = (await getVotingsCount()).toNumber()``` works and ```getVotingQuestion()``` does not

Comment: What does getVotingQuestion() return? We know at this point that your updateUIValues() runs.

Comment: returns string memory

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: my function ```createVoting``` shouldn't call when i deploy VotingEngine, i have ```pages\create.js``` page, there is a button which creates a voting and calls ```createVoting```. I just wanted to my ```index.js``` page somehow rerenders when i create a new voting. I will look a little bit later your request, thx

Comment: Then create voting before you call to it. You are obviously calling to an empty contract.

Comment: even if i created a voting on create page, when i return to the index page, it doesnt rerenders, how can i rerender if new voting created? I need to listen to event? Any ideas?

Comment: Either that or I would just use a different library. I would recommend using Wagmi. useContractRead() hook allows you to watch and refresh data on new blocks. In addition, front end Moralis that you are using is version 1, and it is mostly depreciated at this point. More on it here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147255/is-it-good-for-me-to-switch-to-moralis-from-web3js/147265#147265